# Android LayoutTransition - how to exclude a view

Tags: android, android-layout, layouttransition

I am using `LayoutTransition` to do automatic rearrangement animations in one of my layouts.

I have a requirement to exclude a given child view in this layout from being animated (APPEAR animation). I still want any other views to do the APPEAR effect. So I cannot simply disable APPEAR effect.

I couldn't yet figure out a way to achieve this.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Androbean.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any better solution apart from wrapping the view I want to exclude in a `FrameLayout` (or `ViewGroup` you prefer) and add `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` to it.